# Why is component equal to undefined?

Tags: reactjs

There is a navigation bar, I want the corresponding component to be transferred to the App when clicking on each item. state (boolean variable) is passed, but the component is not, it is always equal to undefiend.

I'm new to React, so I decided to turn here, because I'm not entirely sure that I am correctly passing data from component to component, I would be grateful for your answers

---

App

```
function App() {

const [data, setData] = useState({state: true, panel: <></>})
const handleData = (state, panel) => {
    setData(state, panel)
}
const component = useRef();
const slider = useRef();

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let ctx = gsap.context(() => {
        let panels = gsap.utils.toArray(".panel");
        gsap.to(panels, {
            xPercent: -100 * (panels.length - 1),
            ease: "none",
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: slider.current,
                pin: true,
                scrub: 0.5,
                snap: 0 / (panels.length - 1),
                end: () => "+=" + slider.current.offsetWidth
            }
        });
    }, component);
    return () => ctx.revert();
})

return (
    <>
        {
            !data.state ?
                (<>
                    <div style={{display: 'none'}} ref={component}>
                        <div ref={slider}></div>
                    </div>
                    <div><Header handleData={handleData} position='absolute' /></div>
                    <div>{data.panel}</div>
                </>
                )
                :
                (<div className="App" ref={component}>
                    <div><Header handleData={handleData} position={'fixed'} /></div>
                    <div ref={slider} className="container">
                        <div className="panel"><Main/></div>
                        <div className="panel"><About/></div>
                        <div className="panel"><Works/></div>
                        <div className="panel"><Services/></div>
                        <div className="panel"><Contacts/></div>
                    </div>
                </div>)
            }

    </>
);}
```

Header

```
export const Header = (props) => {
const handleData = props.handleData
const position = props.position

return (
    <>
        <div style={{position: position}} className={classes.wrapper}>
            <div className={classes.label}>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.navBar}>
                <NavBar handleData={handleData} />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.socialMedia}>

            </div>
        </div>
    </>
);}
```

NavBar

```
const menuData = [{
name: 'Main', scroll: function () {
    scroll.scrollToTop()
},
panel: <Main/>
},
{
    name: 'About', scroll: function () {
        scroll.scrollTo(window.innerWidth)
    },
    panel: <About/>
},
{
    name: 'Works', scroll: function () {
        scroll.scrollTo(window.innerWidth * 2)
    },
    panel: <Works/>
},
{
    name: 'Services, scroll: function () {
        scroll.scrollTo(window.innerWidth * 3)
    },
    panel: <Services/>
},
{
    name: 'Contacts', scroll: function () {
        scroll.scrollToBottom()
    },
    panel: <Contacts/>
}]

export const NavBar = (props) => {
const [activeIndex, setActive] = useState(0)
const Scroll = require('react-scroll');
const scroll = Scroll.animateScroll;

const handleData = props.handleData

return (
    <>
        <div className={classes.bar}>
            {
                menuData.map((item, index) => (
                    <MenuItem
                        key={item}
                        item={item}
                        isSelected={activeIndex === index}
                        handleClick={() => {
                            setActive(index)
                            handleData(false, item.panel)
                        }}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </div>
    </>
);
```

}